# Querying firebase HTTPs function in a loop only invokes the last call multiple times

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When a user logs into my app I want to send initial details (like a list of the user's contacts) to the backend to handle user creation. As this is a long job, I thought to split into separate HTTPs calls.

For the sake of simplicity, here is the app-side request:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    data.put("val", String.valueOf(i));
    firebaseFunctions.getHttpsCallable("sandbox").call(data)
        .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.e("Error; " + e.getMessage()))
        .addOnSuccessListener(result -> Log.v("Success! Got " + result.getData()));
}
```

and the HTTPs function (in Node.js):

```
exports.sandbox = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    console.log("In, data.val is " + data.val);
});
```

If I call the function via the `firebase functions:shell` shell like so:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    sandbox.post('').json({"data": {"val": "" + i}});
}
```

I get the output:

```
In, data.val is 0
In, data.val is 1
In, data.val is 2
```

But if the app code runs, the Firebase console show the following log:

```
2018-05-16T10:09:02.080247334Z D sandbox: Function execution started
2018-05-16T10:09:02.080333313Z D sandbox: Billing account not configured. 
    External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. 
    Configure billing account to remove these restrictions
2018-05-16T10:09:03.051Z I sandbox: In, data.val is 2
2018-05-16T10:09:03.135023272Z D sandbox: Function execution took 1056 ms, finished with status code: 200
2018-05-16T10:09:04.073804790Z D sandbox: Function execution started
2018-05-16T10:09:04.073930247Z D sandbox: Billing account not configured. 
    External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. 
    Configure billing account to remove these restrictions
2018-05-16T10:09:04.236Z I sandbox: In, data.val is 2
2018-05-16T10:09:04.239244077Z D sandbox: Function execution took 166 ms, finished with status code: 200
2018-05-16T10:09:06.722270621Z D sandbox: Function execution started
2018-05-16T10:09:06.722387172Z D sandbox: Billing account not configured. 
    External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. 
    Configure billing account to remove these restrictions
2018-05-16T10:09:09.963Z I sandbox: In, data.val is 2
2018-05-16T10:09:09.971406186Z D sandbox: Function execution took 3250 ms, finished with status code: 200
```

I'm seeing `In, data.val is 2` three times. What's going on?

Comment: What exactly did you find confusing? Is it that the value is 2 each invocation?

Comment: Yes, I'll clear that up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `firebaseFunctions.getHttpsCallable("sandbox").call(data)` is asynchronous, meaning it returns immediately.  Your code will kick off three calls in rapid succession.

Also bear in mind that they are all sharing the same `data` object.  What's probably happening here is that the "final" resting value of data contains a key of val with a value of 2.  This is likely what each of the three invocations will end up sending to the function, because the loop is going to finish executing before each request is made.

Instead of modifying the same `data` in each iteration of the loop, create a **new** data object, and populate it with all the data that each request needs (don't reuse the data object between requests).